# Returning the success or failure of processing an array using foreach

Tags: php, function, return-value

I have a PHP function that has an array as a parameter, and I am using `foreach` to process the array. My question is, how can i return a `true` or `false` by using the condition that the function has done the process of the `foreach` thoroughly without finding any failure on one of the steps of the process inside the `foreach`?

Something like:

```
function do_process($array_vars){
    foreach($array_vars as $array_var) {
        //do the process
    }

    return (foreach process success) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: `done the process of foreach thoroughly` ? `foreach` has never failed for me~

Comment: i mean when one of the step of the process inside the foreach fails, sorry i'll edit my question

Comment: Please don't use the `foreach:`/`endforeach` syntax, it causes me physical pain.

Comment: that makes more sense =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on what you mean by "thoroughly".
You can abort as soon as something goes wrong:

```
function foo($array) {
    foreach ($array as $foo) {
        if (/* something or other */) {
            return false;
        }
        ...
    }
    return true;
}
```

Or you can continue through the rest of the array but remember that something went wrong:

```
function foo($array) {
    $success = true;
    foreach ($array as $foo) {
        if (/* something or other */) {
            $success = false;
        }
        ...
    }
    return $success;
}
```

Comment: does this ensure, that array is completely processed?

Comment: @Aqeel What exactly does that mean? `foreach` always goes through all array elements. Any of your processing that may fail is up to you to detect.

Answer (score 2):

You can return from a function at any point, including from within the foreach loop when you detect failure:

```
function do_process($array_vars){
   foreach($array_vars as $array_var) {
     // do the process
     if (this step of the process failed)
       return false;
   }

   // The foreach loop must have completed successfully
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do this like this:

```
function do_process($array_vars){
    $success = true;
    foreach($array_vars as $array_var){
        if (some condition appeared){ $success = false; }
    }

    return $success;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it that way.

```
function process($array_items) {

   foreach($array_items as $item) {
      //processing to array goes here......
      if($some_bottle_neck or $failure)
          return false;
      if($item == end($array_items))
          return true;
   }
}
```

Hopefully this is your solution.

Comment: The whole `$thorough_process` variable is useless, just `return true` at the end. If the function `returns false` before, it'll already `return false`. Also, this has a bug if an array contains two equal values.